# Is there any way or event to know when my IE addon gets disabled?

Tags: c#, bho, ieaddon

I would like to know or track the moment user is disabling my add-on of Internet Explorer.
Is there any way to monitor/track this?

Problem: I have one add-on application which track some sites on browser but user can disable it for their convinience. I want to know if this kind of action is happing with add-on. So that I can enable it through another utility which is capable to enbale it again.

Comment: As an aside, I would have no intention of ever use a product that is notified when I disable it.

Comment: Side note: please avoid adding text unrelated to main problem in posts. Leave stories about name changes, searching and trying to your personal blog/site.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart this is my requirement, Can't change it. Add-on will be on user 's browser and he/she can disable it and this act will stop  my add-on's function and i'll not be having track on that user's machine! Just to make it possible i m looking for a solution to get updated when user is disabling any Browser extension (Add -on).

Comment: You could just start your "other utility" when user log on, and poll the registry.

Comment: @manuell thanks for suggestion , i did the same & already created a utility to manage on machine start up. :)